# How to use wp_dequeue to keep a script from loading in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, api, maps

The theme author is loading the Google Maps API but it isn't being used on the site so I want to dequeue it in the child theme's functions.php. They don't offer an option to simply disable it within the theme settings.

Would someone mind helping me out with the wp_dequeue code? Also, is it technically more efficient to comment it out in the parent theme or dequeue it in the child theme? I know the inherent problems with modifying the parent theme code, but I doubt the author is going to update this theme in future. Thanks!

```
wp_enqueue_script('bazien-google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='.$bazien_theme_options['google_maps_api'], array(), '1.0', FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it the best WordPress way, you'll need to deregister it in the child theme. to do so, use the following :

```
wp_deregister_script( 'bazien-google-maps' );
```

It should make the job. To answer the other question, it's more efficient to comment it in the parent theme, because this way you don't load the script to "unload" it after. But, as you truly said, an update might appear somedays, so it's more secure to disable it in the child theme.

See the cod WordPress for more informations aboubt registering scripts and styles : [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/)
and informations about deregistering : [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script)

Comment: Thanks, @kevinniel!

Comment: many thanks this is so helpful

Comment: again me  - is this enough?? . ....wp_deregister_script( 'bazien-google-maps' );